# Which context confuses this Perl 6 zip operator?

Tags: raku, zip-operator

Consider this program where I create a hash. I want to then change two values in it:

```
my $hash = %(
    wallet   => 100,
    gave     =>   0,
    received =>   0,
    );

for ^1 { $hash<wallet gave> Z+= <-1 1> };

dd $hash;
```

Like this, the last line of `for` doesn't do anything and there is no warning. The hash is unchanged:

```
Hash $hash = ${:gave(0), :received(0), :wallet(100)}
```

Adding another statement changes the behavior:

```
my $hash = %(
    wallet   => 100,
    gave     =>   0,
    received =>   0,
    );

for ^1 { $hash<wallet gave> Z+= <-1 1>; True };

dd $hash;
```

Now the inplace edit does its thing, but there's a warning (although I dispute "useless" when I've found a use for it):

```
Useless use of constant value True in sink context
Hash $hash = ${:gave(1), :received(0), :wallet(99)}
```

If I do without the `Z+=`, which should be the same thing, it works:

```
my $hash = %(
    wallet   => 100,
    gave     =>   0,
    received =>   0,
    );

for ^1 { $hash<wallet gave> = $hash<wallet gave> Z+ <-1 1> }

dd $hash;
```

Again the right output:

```
Hash $hash = ${:gave(1), :received(0), :wallet(99)}
```

Comment: That looks like a bug. Likely a sink context handling bug. `for ^1 { sink $hash<wallet gave> Z+= <-1 1> };` or `for ^1 { say $hash<wallet gave> Z+= <-1 1> };` both give the correct results.

Comment: I had tried throwing sink in there and saw that it worked. Odd.

Comment: FWIW, what version of Rakudo Perl 6 are you using?  I recall a bug about not sinking the final value in a `for` loop being fixed quite recently.

Comment: I'm using the latest Rakudo *, 2017.04.

Comment: Maybe related to this commit https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/acece7b2f7a8614c40d832a76ff67be2a71d851a

Comment: I am still able to reproduce here: https://glot.io/snippets/evpyszdfgh

Comment: I confirmed that this is still a problem with 2017.10.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [bug](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/1531). Fixed as of Rakudo 2018.02.1-45-g8a10fc1