# Last element of a block thrown in sink context

Tags: raku

This program

```
my @bitfields;
for ^3 -> $i {
    @bitfields[$i] = Bool.pick xx 3;
}

my @total = 0 xx 3;
for @bitfields -> @row {
    @total Z+= @row;
}
say @total;
```

says `[0 0 0]`. If we add something to the loop, whatever:

```
my @bitfields;
for ^3 -> $i {
    @bitfields[$i] = Bool.pick xx 3;
}

my @total = 0 xx 3;
for @bitfields -> @row {
    @total Z+= @row;
    say "foo";
}
say @total;
```

It will work correctly. Apparently, the last element of the block is thrown into sink context which in this case means it's simply ignored; this [trap](https://docs.perl6.org/language/traps#Phasers_and_implicit_return) is related to that. However, that code above looks perfectly fine; and this

```
{@total Z+= @^þ} for @bitfields;
```

apparently works, although I don't see the real difference. Any other idea?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like a bug to me.

This looks very closely related to [Which context confuses this Perl 6 zip operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45001820/which-context-confuses-this-perl-6-zip-operator) which became a Rakudo repo issue [Failure to sink `for` when `Z+=` used as last statement](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/1531) which was closed with roast tests [Test sunk for sinks last statement sub calls](https://github.com/perl6/roast/commit/01b59fba66bde1e616b91afbbfc0f89b7727f05a) .

The mystery is why there's a new bug. My suspicion is that someone needs to clean the kitchen sink, i.e. pick up where Zoffix left off with his [Flaws in implied sinkage / `&unwanted` helper](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/1571) issue.

Here's my best golf shot so far for narrowing down the new problem or regression:

```
my $foo = 'a';
ok:              for 1       { $foo X= 'b' }
notok:           for 1 -> $_ { $foo X= 'c' }
say $foo; # b
halfok: 'd' ~ do for 1 -> $_ { $foo X= 'e' } # Useless use of "~"
say $foo; # e
```

The `ok:` line works because it omits the `->` argument.

The `notok:` line is my golf of your problem.

The error message for the `halfok:` line is because the result of it is thrown away. But the `do` has forced the compiler to evaluate the `$foo X= 'e'` expression in the block, as it should, and as it had failed to in the `notok:` line.

> ```
> {@total Z+= @^þ} for @bitfields;
> ```

Perhaps that's because that's the non-modifier version. And/or because it doesn't use the `->` syntax (which is part of the regression or new bug per my golf above).

Or perhaps just luck. I think most of the sink handling code in Rakudo is Larry's work from long ago when he was trying to get things mostly working right.