# Cumulative Z op throws a "The iterator of this Seq is already in use/consumed by another Seq"

Tags: raku

This is another way of solving [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54466631/last-element-of-a-block-thrown-in-sink-context)

```
my @bitfields;
for ^3 -> $i {
    @bitfields[$i] = Bool.pick xx 3;
}

my @total = [\Z+] @bitfields;
say @total;
```

It should zip-add every row to the next one, and accumulate the value. However, this yields the error

```
The iterator of this Seq is already in use/consumed by another Seq
(you might solve this by adding .cache on usages of the Seq, or
by assigning the Seq into an array)
  in block <unit> at vanishing-total.p6 line 8
```

Any idea how this might be solved?

Comment: This looks like a bug to me: as you are not using any `Seq` explicitly in your code, there should be no way for you to make this error happen.  Please create an issue.

Comment: workaround: `([\Z+] @bitfields).map(*.list)`; not sure if it's really a bug - the sequences are created by `Z`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First `xx` creates a Sequence

```perl6
say (Bool.pick xx 3).^name; # Seq
```

So you probably want to turn that into an Array (or List).

```perl6
for ^3 -> $i {
    @bitfields[$i] = [Bool.pick xx 3];
}
```

Also rather than `.pick xx 3`, I would use `.roll(3)`.

```perl6
for ^3 -> $i {
    @bitfields[$i] = [Bool.roll(3)];
}
```

The zip (`Z`) meta operator creates Sequences as well.

```perl6
say ( [1,2] Z [3,4] ).perl;
# ((1, 3), (2, 4)).Seq

say ( [1,2] Z+ [3,4] ).perl
# (4, 6).Seq
```

So `[\Z+]` won't even work the way you want for two inputs.

```perl6
say [\Z+]( [1,2], [3,4] ).perl;
# (Seq.new-consumed(), Seq.new-consumed()).Seq

say [\Z+]( 1, 2 ).perl;
# (Seq.new-consumed(), Seq.new-consumed()).Seq
```

It does work if you do something to cache the intermediate values.

```perl6
say [\Z+]( [1,2], [3,4] ).map(*.cache).perl
# ((3,), (4, 6)).Seq

say [\Z+]( [1,2], [3,4] ).map(*.list).perl
# ((3,), (4, 6)).Seq

say [\Z+]( [1,2], [3,4] ).map(*.Array).perl
# ([3], [4, 6]).Seq
```

---

You might want to also add a list to the front, and a `.skip`.

```perl6
my @bitfields = [
  [Bool::True,  Bool::True,  Bool::False],
  [Bool::False, Bool::False, Bool::True ],
  [Bool::False, Bool::True,  Bool::True ]
];

say [\Z+](  @bitfields  ).map(*.List)
# ((2) (1 1 1) (1 2 2))

say [\Z+](  (0,0,0), |@bitfields  ).map(*.List).skip
# ((1 1 0) (1 1 1) (1 2 2))
```

---

If you don't need the intermediate results `[Z+]` would work just fine.

```perl6
say [Z+]( Bool.roll(3) xx 3 ) for ^5;
# (0 1 3)
# (1 2 1)
# (1 0 3)
# (0 1 2)
# (1 2 2)
```