# Is Raku dropping exceptions when a loop variable is used?

Tags: exception, raku

I really can't find another explanation for this:

```
for <a b> -> $foo {
    spurt "a/b", "bar";
}
say "Gotcha";
for <a b>  {
    spurt "a/b", "bar";
}
```

This prints "Gotcha" and then fails. I get that the last value in a loop is returned, and that if nothing is done with it it's in [sink context](https://docs.raku.org/language/contexts#index-entry-sink_context), but what kind of change brings declaring a variable to it? It's still a [`Block`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Block), far as I can tell.

Comment: Didn't you revert the order of the parameters of `spurt`?  Assuming you want to write to a file called "bar"

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen But then it works. I presume JJ's point is that writing to "a/b" fails because there's no "a" directory. But the failure passes unreported. Yet in the second block the failure crashes the program. Why the difference?

Comment: The second block signature `(;; $_? is raw = OUTER::<$_?>)`, the first `($foo)`. That doesn't explain it at all but I wanted to note it.

Comment: If I replace the `spurt`s by `Failure.new` (which is the equivalent I would say in this situation), then both loops throw with the line number of the `for`, and a postscript "Actually thrown at" with the line number of the `Failure.new`.  Is this also what you see?  Or do you see something different?

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen I don't think I did... https://docs.perl6.org/language/independent-routines#sub_spurt; I want to write to "a/b" which is why it fails, `a` does not exist. @raiph is right. Anyway, I was curious why it failed in this situation... Maybe it's not the same as directly creating a failure.

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen That was about the first thing I tried. On repl.it (`say $*RAKU.compiler.version; # v2020.02.1`), tio.run (`say $*PERL.compiler.version; # v2018.12`), and glot.io (`v2018.04.1`), I saw the same as what JJ reported in his question body, and the same as what you report when replacing the `spurt`s with `Failure.new`s. So while they might (seem to) be *logically* equivalent, they're not *actually* equivalent in those three Rakudo installations covering mid 2018 thru to today.

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this? It smells to me like [another bug in the kitchen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54469963/1077672).

Comment: @raiph I didn't. Maybe I'll post an issue in rakudo.

Comment: @jjmerelo Hopefully you saw that for the bug I linked "`->` syntax [was] part of the regression or new bug" which suggests it's related to this one and suggests that "`->` and sinking" or somesuch is the appropriate topic for a bug report that could then cite both this SO and the earlier one by you that I linked as examples. I'll post an issue of that form later today if I don't see one already there.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Rakudo 2022.07**

*returns:*

```perl
Gotcha
Failed to open file /Users/admin/a/b: No such file or directory
  in block <unit> at - line 6
```