# Raku cloned object not sunk

Tags: clone, raku, sink

```
class A {
  has $.n;

# If this method is uncommented then the clone won't be sunk  
#  method clone {
#    my $clone = callwith(|%_);
#    return $clone;
#  }

  method sink(-->Nil) { say "sinking...$!n" }
}

sub ccc(A:D $a) { $a.clone(n=>2) }

ccc(A.new(n=>1));
say 'Done';
```

Above prints:

```
sinking...2
Done
```

However, if the custom `clone` method is used, then the returned clone from `ccc` won't be sunk for some reason. It works if I `sink` it explicitly at call site or if I change the `my $clone = callwith(|%_)` line to `my $clone := callwith(|%_)`. Is this expected? What's the reason that it's working this way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of filed-and-still-open-years-later sink bugs (and, I suspect, loads that have not been filed).

As touched on in [my answer to **Last element of a block thrown in sink context**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54469963/1077672):

> someone needs to clean the kitchen sink, i.e. pick up where Zoffix left off with his [Flaws in implied sinkage / &unwanted helper](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/1571) issue.

Zoffix's conclusion was:

> So given there are so many issues with the system, I'm just wondering if there isn't a better one that can be used to indicate whether something is wanted or not.

Fast forward 2 years, and a better system is hopefully going to land. In [a recent grant report](https://news.perlfoundation.org/post/rakuast-2020-06) jnthn writes:

> The current code doing this work in Rakudo is difficult to follow and not terribly efficient. ... Since RakuAST models the language at a higher level and defers producing QAST until much later, a far cleaner solution to the sink analysis problem is possible. ... I'm optimistic that the model I've created will be flexible enough to handle all the sinking-related requirements

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what is going on yet, but removing the `return` statement makes the cloned object call the right `sink` method.

I've created an issue for it: https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/3855

Comment: It's a bug, I see. Thanks!